# How move element from end of column 1 to end of column 2 at md breakpoint without duplication

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4, flexbox

I have a rough Bootstrap 4 layout that has a set of buttons that needs to be at the end of the layout on the small breakpoint and lower. On the medium breakpoint and above I want the button set to be at the end of the first column.

In the codepen linked below, I am using two instances of the same button set and hiding one set on mobile and the other on desktop breakpoints.

Is there a way to use only one button set using CSS and flexbox to achieve the same effect without duplication?

[Codepen](https://codepen.io/jpmoran/pen/bGwEqEG)

```html
<div class="container py-5 bg-success">
  <div class="row row-cols-1 row-cols-md-3 justify-content-center align-items-center text-center">
    
<!-- Left Column -->
    <div class="col py-4 bg-warning">
      <h2>People LOVE<br> Our Awsome Product</h2>
      <div class="d-none d-md-block text-light bg-dark">
            <a href="#" class="btn btn-outline-primary btn-block d-sm-inline" />Read More Reviews</a>
      <a href="#" class="btn btn-link" />Shop Now</a>
    </div>
    </div>
                                     
<!-- Right Column -->
    <div class="col py-4 bg-info">
      <img class="img-fluid rounded-circle mb-2" src="https://via.placeholder.com/300" />
      <p class="font-italic">This is some really awsome testimonial about our product and how it changed their life.</p>
      <small>Verified User 5 Star</small>
    </div>
    
    <!-- mobile buttons -->
 <div class="col-12 d-md-none bg-light py-3">
      <a href="#" class="btn btn-outline-primary btn-block d-sm-inline" />Read More Reviews</a>
      <a href="#" class="btn btn-link" />Shop Now</a>
    </div>
  </div> 


</div>
```

Comment: It can't be done while it's contained in a column as far as I'm aware, however, if you could break it out then you could use `order` to change it's placement on different device sizes

Comment: Can you show me an example of what breaking it out would look like?